# Installing packages which downloads files in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install following packages in Ubuntu 14.04 but getting the following error:

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading    
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 239, in    
process_download_requests
dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
```

I am working behind a proxy server but proxy settings are working fine for all other package installations. I am also getting this same error when installing flashplugin-installer. I have checked the environment variables i.e http_proxy, https_proxy and ftp_proxy and they are set with appropriate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error with Mint 17 and it seems to occur in Ubuntu 14.04. It's a known bug (see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/979477) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/982684)).

What I did to solve was:

```
sudo su
```

if you're proxy requires authentication:

```
export http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<your_proxy>:<proxy_port>
```

if i doesn't require authentication:

```
export http_proxy=http://<your_proxy>:<proxy_port>
```

and finally install the package like you would normally do

```
apt-get install <package_to_install>
```

or reinstall the package in case you already had install it

```
apt-get install --reinstall <package_to_install>
```

I tested with ttf-mscorefonts-installer but I guess that it should also work with flashplugin-installer.